# Meteor + React + Semantic UI - What is the best way to install this stack?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I want to use React and meteor together with Semantic UI.

I see that Semantic has an [official atmosphere package](https://atmospherejs.com/semantic/ui)

There is also a [Semantic-UI-React](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React) project

What is the best way to install this stack?

Is there any reason(s) that it doesn't make sense at all?

Would react-router also fit in the stack?

Comment: To begin with, are you sure to pick semantic-ui-react? Because I struggled with an issue, when you need to make custom style for a component  (for example color prop doesnt have an required color) it will override your color with an original color. With that speaking, it will always read built-in styles (semantic-ui.min.css) instead of yours, unless you specify every style as "!important", but this... is bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a starter repo for MeteorJS + ReactJS I've written. I have also installed semantic-ui under `/client/lib`

https://github.com/pkcwong/meteor-react-starter

I am a huge fan of ReactJS and semantic-ui.

Basically you first install semantic-ui-react, then you still have to follow this link to install the actual semantic-ui library.

https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Meteor

Answer (score 2):

We have a boilerplate that may help you. It’s using the following components:
- Meteor V 1.7.0.3
- React 16.4.1
- React Router V4.3.1
- Semantic-ui-react 0.81.1

https://github.com/factoryThings/fTboilerplate

Comment: Looks really great! Thanks for the pointer. Can you say how you decided which Atmosphere packages to use and which NPM?

Comment: I ask because I recently read this priority: [As less as possible dependencies to Atmosphere. I.e. try to only use packages from NPM.](https://medium.com/melonport-blog/from-blaze-to-react-43097df5fc71)

Comment: Glad you like the boilerplate. Indeed, we tried to minimise the use of Atmosphere packages: - For semantic-ui, we use npm directly (semantic-ui-react) instead of the semantic:ui package - For the router, we use the popular "react-router" instead of the Flow or Iron router packages.

Comment: I opened an issue [#2](https://github.com/factoryThings/fTboilerplate/issues/2) to ask about the package decisions and css customization options

Comment: For information, we decided a while ago to adopt antd framework (backed by Alibaba). More components, more React.

Comment: ok, so for antd - how did you integrate it into your stack - simple meteor npm install? or was there more to it?

Comment: clean, current as of this comment, installs and starts up with zero issues, great starting point, thanks!

Comment: @gihef, I asked another question about the antd stack here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096715/meteor-react-antd-how-to-speed-up-build-rebuild-time-avoid-less-plugin-d did you publish an antd boilplate or find strategies for dealing with the less plugin slowdown?

Comment: We didn't yet publish the antd boilerplate but this is clearly in my todo list! We experienced quite slow build indeed (especially after the meteor 1.7 upgrade) but we didn't yet investigate deeply as we are fully busy on another task for a few weeks.

Comment: For information, we eventually published a boilerplate for antD at https://github.com/factoryThings/fTboilerplate-antd