# Meteor + React + Antd - How to speed up build/rebuild time? (avoid less plugin delay)

Tags: reactjs, meteor, antd, meteor-react

Uninstalling antd from my meteor project drops the build time by 38-40s on average. The profiler shows that plugin less needs >38s to deal with antd's huge less archive:

```
VELOCITY_DEBUG=1 VELOCITY_DEBUG_MIRROR=1 METEOR_PROFILE=1 meteor | grep less
...
| other plugin less.......................................38,766 ms (2)
...
```

this number drops to <1s (572ms) when i uninstall antd:

```
| other plugin less..........................................572 ms (2)
```

> >30s is simply too long to wait for the app to refresh during development.

Does anyone know a strategy to avoid this delay?

Comment: There is an issue on the meteor project: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/9957

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the upcoming meteor update fixes this.

I updated to the recent beta:

```
meteor update --release 1.7.1-beta.10
```

restarted meteor with the profiler:

```
VELOCITY_DEBUG=1 VELOCITY_DEBUG_MIRROR=1 METEOR_PROFILE=1 meteor --inspect | grep 'less\|Total'
```

and now the less plugin is taking way less than 1 second on file save 
and total rebuild time is back within reason:

```
|    │     │  ├─ plugin less                                       45 ms (2)
| (#5) Total: 4,270 ms (Rebuild App)
```

Comment: for information, we eventually published a boilerplate with Meteor (1.8 rc17) and Antd at https://github.com/factoryThings/fTboilerplate-antd. It's using Less and is building fast.